# Find all directories which has only one type of file

Tags: linux, operating-systems

Given a file type .txt, find all directories that has only that type of file.

For example

```
a--
   b-- 1.txt
   c--
      |
       ---- 2.jpg
       ---- 3.txt
```

The command should output only `b` not `c`.

Comment: Please add an OS tag. For Linux: I'd probably run `find`, get candidate directories which at least contain this type of file, and post-process the output via a script that checks the "only" condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type d -execdir sh -c '
   [ "$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" -print -quit | wc -l)" -gt 0 ] &&
   [ "$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.txt" -print -quit | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]
   ' find-sh {} \; -print
```

The outer `find` supplies directories to be examined. Two inner `find`-s check if there is at least one `.txt` file and no non-`.txt` files in the directory. `sh` shell implements logic with `[ … ]` and `&&`.

Notes:

- `-maxdepth` is not required by POSIX. For POSIX approach see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618).
- `-quit` is not required by POSIX. This action makes `find` quit as soon as any matching file is reported. It's useful because we need at most one matching file to obtain the result with `wc -l` and `[ … ]`, so quitting early saves time. Without `-quit` the whole command will work, it will just be slower when there are many files. Alternatively you can use `find … | head -n 1 | wc -l`; in this case `head` will terminate the pipe after the first file found, `wc` will yield the result right away, but `find` will only notice the broken pipe when (if) it tries to write *yet another* line. And it's a trade-off: `head` may save you some time and resources but (as a separate process) it needs time and resources to be spawned twice in every directory.
- Paths with newlines (if any) will fool `wc -l` but it doesn't matter because these extra newlines may add to the count only if the "right" count is non-zero anyway, and we only need to know whether the result is zero or not.